# Foundation 6 - Sticky menu and off canvas content

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Im facing problem when i use sticky navbar with off canvas.

**Problem**: Once I click on hamburger icon, off canvas will popup but navbar will be moved to top of the page and not on top of the viewport. It should remain on the same position as when clicked on hamburger icon.

**Test case**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaGaPM

**HTML**:

```
<div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvasLeftOverlap" data-off-canvas data-transition="push">
    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="vertical menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1A</a>
                    <ul class="vertical menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1E</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="vertical menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 2A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul class="vertical menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 3A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>

    <div class="scrollhide-nav">
        <div class="title-bar">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="offCanvasLeftOverlap"></button>
            <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).foundation();
var nav_prev = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.scrollhide-nav').toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > nav_prev);
    nav_prev = scrollTop;
});
```

**SCSS**:

```
.scrollhide-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.4, 1);

  &.hidden {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .is-open-left & {

  }
}
```

Comment: You hide `.scrollhide-nav` on scroll, what do you expect?

Comment: Its visible once you scroll a little to the top. It should remain in that position.

Comment: Because after you click on hamburger icon it give `.off-canvas-content.is-open-left.has-transition-push` class to parent div, and it has `transform: translate()` you should make parent position fixed not child.